# File downloaded with wget has wrong encoding

Tags: linux, encoding

We have a page on our intranet which is just `plain/text` encoded in `UTF-8` and it contais insert scripts for database. And problem is, when I download this page to a file with `wget` or `curl`, my downloaded file has UTF-8 encoding but special characters(Czech language chars) are broken.

So where could be a problem?I can convert it to CP-1250 encoding which works fine(I also tried ISO8859-2, it doesn't work either), but I can't use it for db insert via SQL*Plus, because our DB is encoded in UTF-8.

Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: I think your file is downloaded correctly. Nor the web server, nor wget, nor curl ever modify the files. So first check your file is okay on the web server and/or compare the checksum of the original file and the checksum of the downloaded file.

Comment: How did you check that the file is broken?  (Which program / editor?)

Comment: @AndreasFlorath How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

The HTTP protocol communicates in US_ASCII.

Therefore, plain/text content CAN NOT be UTF-8: it **must** be encoded if it contains non-ASCII UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Sorry - but this is complete nonsense: please consult RFC 2616, Section 3.6.

Comment: Transfer-coding ? How does that apply ?

Comment: _However, safe transport has a different focus for an 8bit-clean transfer protocol._ RFC 2616, Section 3.6